# Abp One to many Relationship

Tags: abp

I have Book and Author Entity.
I tried to establish a relationship between Book and Author, but the AuthorId key did not appear. I wonder how it is done.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkJW4.jpg)

Comment: show us the Book.cs code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I think you are looking at the tutorials part of the ABP framework document. If you haven't looked, I think you should look at [this](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Tutorials/Part-10?UI=MVC&DB=EF#update-the-ef-core-mapping).

As explained in the document, you can do this as follows:

Open the BookStoreDbContextModelCreatingExtensions class under the EntityFrameworkCore folder of the Acme.BookStore.EntityFrameworkCore project and change the builder.Entity part as shown below

```
builder.Entity<Book>(b =>
{
  b.ToTable(BookStoreConsts.DbTablePrefix + "Books", BookStoreConsts.DbSchema);
  b.ConfigureByConvention(); //auto configure for the base class props
  b.Property(x => x.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(128);

  // ADD THE MAPPING FOR THE RELATION
  b.HasOne<Author>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.AuthorId).IsRequired();
});
```